# Read an image to a byte array using php

Tags: php, image, arrays

Using **php** I need to read an image to a byte stream which has to be passed to a .NET web service. Can anyone provide me with a **php** code snippet to read an image to a byte array ? I am using using php 5.
thanks

Comment: what I mean is to read the image and assign it to a byte array :)

Comment: FYI: You've probably received that downvote for your 'pass me the codez' attitude. You may wish to consider editing your question such that it demonstrates a will to learn and work with those who are helping you. In addition you should provide some more details about how you want the byte stream to be formatted.

Comment: thanks for the info. I had to ask this way because I needed an urgent solution and I just started programming with php. Anyway I'll consider of editing the question once I try the suggested answer given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe PHP natively supports byte arrays in the same sense that .NET does.  However, you could try converting each character to its ASCII representation:

```
<?
$file = file_get_contents($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']);
$byteArr = str_split($file);
foreach ($byteArr as $key=>$val) { $byteArr[$key] = ord($val); }
?>
```

Source: http://www.experts-exchange.com/Web_Development/Web_Languages-Standards/PHP/Q_23325692.html